# React {useState, useEffect). How often React renders with single "useEffect", which triggers a 'setState' in a callback?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Here I expected 3x rendering.

1. From the initial mount.
2. From the only 'useEffect'
3. From the 'setValue(data)', which comes with the axios-callback.

Why are there only 2 renders?

```
const Main = () => {
 const [value, setValue] = useState("");

 useEffect( () => {
    fetch()
  }, []);

const fetch = () => {
  axios.get(url)
  .then(data => {
    setValue(data)
  });
};

console.log("before render");  // 2x "before render"

return (...);
};

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect doesn't trigger a re-render, it simply calls the callback provided to the effect. Only state modifications cause re-renders.

Comment: @Viktor_W Thanks. Tough I have one more question, you might help me with:

Why do I get 3 renders, when:
 - I remove the '[ ]' in 'useEffect' 
- AND my axios-response is always the same (--> no change in the content of the state).

Comment: Not sure. One theory: Axios returns an object, containing statuscode and stuff like that, right? Say res1 and res2 are the response of the same axios request. Then, `res1 == res2` would always be false, since they are different objects. So when React compares this, it thinks you have assigned a new value. But `res1.data == res2.data` would be true. However, this should have not stopped at 3 renders it should have re-rendered infinitely

Answer (score 1):

Only 2 renders will happen -

```
1- From the initial mount.
2- From the 'setValue(data)', which comes with the axios-callback.
```

like setValue and similar hooks do not immediately re-render your component. They may batch or defer the update until later. So you get only one rerender after the
latest setValue call.

`useEffect` will not trigger a re-render until told so.

Comment: Easy and fast. Thanks. Tough I have one more question, you might help me with:

Why do I get 3 renders, when:
 - I remove the '[ ]' in 'useEffect' 
- AND my axios-response is always the same (--> no change in the content of the state).

Comment: @coasterrel useEffect will run when the component renders, which might be more times than you think. Some links for knowledge
1 - https://www.andreasreiterer.at/react-useeffect-hook-loop/
and 
2- https://css-tricks.com/run-useeffect-only-once/`